# How to automatically rename file name to username value for uploaded user images in WordPress - ultimate memeber plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, web, ultimate-member

When using the Ultimate Member plugin on WordPress, I encountered one difficult problem for me. I need the uploaded user image in his profile to turn into a link like: `http://example.com/img/%username%.png` The path to `%username%.png` is not important (the main thing is that it does not change), but I wanted so that the user's uploaded image has a name that matches the username value. Tell me how this can be implemented, I’m new to PHP and know everything very superficially.

At the moment the link looks like:
`https://example.com/um-download/6287/img/6/93059f79c9?t=1694944149`
The only thing I could cling to is that the letter `6` is the user id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was literally the only shareware `file-renaming-on-upload` plan with such a functionality. In it, you can automate the renaming of files depending on {port} {username} {date} and so on.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/file-renaming-on-upload/

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following code to change the filename of a `stream_photo` using the Ultimate Member Form's Uploader field. This changes the filename to the current logged-in user's `user_login` value when you Upload with the uploader field that has a meta key `second_profile_photo`:

```
add_filter( 'um_image_upload_handler_overrides__second_profile_photo', function( $uploader_overrides ) {
if( 'stream_photo' ===  UM()->uploader()->upload_image_type) {
    $uploader_overrides['unique_filename_callback'] = function ( $dir, $filename, $ext ) {
        if ( empty( $ext ) ) {
            $image_type = wp_check_filetype( $filename );
            $ext = strtolower( trim( $image_type['ext'], ' \/.' ) );
        } else {
            $ext = strtolower( trim( $ext, ' \/.' ) );
        }
    
        if ( 'image' == UM()->uploader()->upload_type ) {
            $filename = um_user('user_login') . ".{$ext}";
        }
    
       UM()->uploader()->delete_existing_file( $filename, $ext, $dir );
    
        return $filename;
    };
}
return $uploader_overrides;
```

} );

This doesn't change the download URL displayed in the Profile View but this let's you generate the uploaded photo with your desired filename.

Further code explanation:

`UM()->uploader()->upload_image_type` checks if the current uploading file is a `stream_photo`.

Ultimate Member has 4 upload types: `profile_photo`, `cover_photo`, `stream_photo` and `file`. In your case, you only need the `stream_photo`.

This is the part that renames the filename with the current logged-in user's `user_login` value:

```
if ( 'image' == UM()->uploader()->upload_type ) {
  $filename = um_user('user_login') . ".{$ext}";
}
```